# How can I run multiple instances of VSCode in a different process job?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows.

Is it possible to run several instances of VSCode in different process groups/jobs?

I had a bad experience of VSCode hanging when debugging while working on other project simultaneously. If one process is terminated, the whole group of processes are terminated too.

Comment: I have (let's say) 2 repos `~/a_repo` and `~/b_repo`. The `a_repo` code requires `TLD=~/a_repo` to be set whereas B requires `TLD=~/b_repo`. 
I set `TLD=~/a_repo` and run `code .` in `~/a_repo`. Fine. 

But if, in another terminal with `TLD=~/b_repo`, I run `code .` in `~/_b_repo` (which opens a new window in the existing `code` process), `TLD` is still `~/a_repo`. 

This means I can edit but not debug both repos, which is a giant PITA.

Comment: The problem on Windows is I haven't different terminals to emulate what you do.

Comment: can't you just start multiple CMD/powershell terminals? Interestingly when I run `code .` from a different terminal, the new Window is just added to the already-running `code` process. I'm not quite sure how this is achieved but it's pretty nifty... but not what I want ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Exactly. It does not attach to a new job/process group